# Problems with Blob acquisition when receiving data through a web-socket

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket

In the process of communicating with the server using a web socket, the data is handed over to the server to Json.
And in the process of receiving data through onmessage, the data came into Blob, not Json or string.
I couldn't find a way to change this Blob to Json, so I posted a question here.

Is there any way to receive the data in string or Json?
Or how to change Blob to string or Json.

The server is written in c++ and sent as a string.

```
useEffect(() => {
        //var socket = new WebSocket("ws://172.30.1.50:65432/websocket");
        const socket = new WebSocket("ws://ip:port/websocket"); //For convenience, I wrote down ip and port.
        socket.Type = "blob"

        socket.onopen = function (event) {
            socket.send(JSON.stringify({ 'CMD': 'test' }))
            console.log("connetion?");}
        
        socket.close
        socket.onmessage = function (event) {
             console.log((event.data))
    }, []})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The WebSocket protocol supports two kinds of data messages: text and binary.  When a text message is received by Javascript, it is deserialised as a string; when a binary message is received, it is deserialised as either an ArrayBuffer or a Blob, depending on the value of the websocket's `binaryType` property (the default is to return a Blob).

The fact that you got a Blob indicates that the server sent a binary message.  This is unusual for a JSON message, so either the server is very unusual, or the protocol is not based on JSON.

In any case, you can convert r data into a string by calling the async `.text()` method:

```
let data = await event.data.text();
```

If the contents is indeed JSON, then you may parse it as usual:

```
let value = JSON.parse(data);
```

Comment: If you use .text(), you can see the contents inside. But this data doesn't show up as the Json we want.

Comment: [[Prototype]]
: 
Promise
[[PromiseState]]
: 
"fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]
: 
"{\"Model\":{\"Drag\":1,\"Earth\":1,\"Moon\":1,\"SRP\":1,\"Sun\":1},\"cd\":2.2,\"cr\":1,\"lgrav\":18,\"mgrav\":18,\"sat_area\":8,\"sat_mass\":1100,\"tilt_ang\":35}"

Comment: Added comment about `JSON.parse`.